# Can't find file when trying to execute it on OS X

Tags: macos

What's up with the following scenario? Using `ls` shows that the `pypy` file is there, but when I try and execute it, it says it's not...

```
pkerp@toc:~/projects/oebb$ lt /opt/local/bin/pypy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    25B Mar 22 15:32 /opt/local/bin/pypy -> pypy-2.5.0-osx64/bin/pypy
===============================================================
pkerp@toc:~/projects/oebb$ /opt/local/bin/pypy
-bash: /opt/local/bin/pypy: No such file or directory
```

The file's there, right? Why can't I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

The file which `/opt/local/bin/pypy` links to does not exist. You need to track down the original executable and relink it in `/opt/local/bin`.